# Sort orderbook when prices are floats

Tags: c++, sorting, floating-point, trading

What is a good way to sort an orderbook on price when the prices are floats/doubles? A binary tree works OK when the prices are integers because you can key off the price and get O(log(n)) add. It's a bad idea or at the very least risky to key off of floats/doubles.

Comment: If it were at all possible, I would strongly suggest you use ints and perform your pricing comparing *cents* (or whatever your currency is). In other words, your first suggestion of using prices as integers would be preferred if you can muster it. Floating point with monetary comparisons is  like oil and water.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I would suggest storing prices as integers. Just make the unit `cents`, `pence`, `öre` or whatever the smaller unit is in your country - or even 1/1000th or 1/10000th of the main currency. This will save a lot of headache later on.

But as long as you are not making `if (x.price == y.price)`, it's perfectly fine to use `price` as a key. For sorting purposes, a binary tree only needs a `less than` (or `greater than`) comparison, which should be perfectly safe for floating point values. A value is always either smaller or bigger than some other value. It's only when you make calculations and try to determine if the value is precisely equal you get problems with floating point. [Or when you expect an exact result from calculations, such as multiplying by 2.46, then dividing by 2.46 and then subtracting the original number, and expecting exactly zero]

Comment: Provided there are no NaNs in the data.

Comment: Ehm, yeah. That would be pretty bad - hopefully most prices are within the range of a float - even the defecit of most countries are, so I think it's rare... ;)